# web services in mvc to get multipart data from android

Tags: android, web-services, spring-mvc

i want to send multiple images in one request to the tomcat server . for that i need to write the web services in spring mvc to fetch the multipart entity of android in java spring mvc.

below is my android code

```
    public void upload() throws Exception {
    //Url of the server
    String url ="http://10.21.xxx.xxx:1010/MultiFileUpload/test";
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    //Path of the file to be uploaded
    String filepath = "";

//Add the data to the multipart entity
    File file1 = new File(filepath);
    ContentBody cbFile1 = new FileBody(file1, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);

File file2 = new File(filepath);
    ContentBody cbFile2 = new FileBody(file2, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);

File file3 = new File(filepath);
    ContentBody cbFile3 = new FileBody(file3, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("image", cbFile);

    mpEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody("Test", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    mpEntity.addPart("data", new StringBody("This is test report", Charset.forName("UTF-8")));


      post.setEntity(mpEntity);
    //Execute the post request
    HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);
    //Get the response from the server
    HttpEntity resEntity = response1.getEntity();
    String Response= EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
    Log.d("Response:", Response);
    //Generate the array from the response
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("["+Response+"]");
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
    //Get the result variables from response
    String result = (jsonobject.getString("result"));
    String msg = (jsonobject.getString("msg"));
    //Close the connection
    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Please help me with the web services. I m facing lot of trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the approach of separating out a model as below

```
public class MultiImage implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 74458L;

    private String name;
    private String data;

    private List<MultipartFile> images;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public List<MultipartFile> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(List<MultipartFile> images) {
        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

Your JSON result can be another POJO or String values here I had done in this way

```
public class UploadResult {
    String result;
    String msg;


    public UploadResult(String result, String msg) {
        this.result = result;
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }


    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }


}
```

Your MVC/service side would be handling this request by going through the model and fetching images and subsequently transfer or saving them on predefined location and wrapping the result in ResponseEntity.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload-image", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity uploadImages(HttpServletRequest servletRequest, @ModelAttribute MultiImage multiImage, Model model) {
        //Get the uploaded images and store them
        List<MultipartFile> images = multiImage.getImages();
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (null != images && images.size() > 0)
        {
            for (MultipartFile multipartFile : images) {
                String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
                fileNames.add(fileName);
                File imageFile = new File(servletRequest.getServletContext().getRealPath("/image"), fileName);
                try
                {
                    multipartFile.transferTo(imageFile);
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        model.addAttribute("images", images);
        UploadResult uploadResult = new UploadResult("Success","Images Uploaded");
        return ResponseEntity.Ok(uploadResult);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @rizwan u made my day

Answer (score 0):

Below code will read the image sending by android/client.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity < String > test(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

     byte[] imageBytes = null;

     try {
      MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
      for (Entry < String, MultipartFile > entry: multipartRequest.getFileMap().entrySet()) {
       imageBytes = entry.getValue().getBytes();
      }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
```